# Django current user is AnonymousUser

Tags: django

I have a pretty simple problem. I have a class that is extending APIView in order to pass in a Json Response to a URL which will be used as an API. I'm trying to filter data from a model so that I only get data items which belong to the current user. Because of this, I'm trying to access request.user.id to set my filter with.

From my views.py, here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []


    def get(self, request, format=None):

        print(self.request.user)
```

When I go to the url associated with this class, the print statement returns AnonymousUser, as if the user does not exist.

In the same views.py file  I have another method (not inside any class) set up as the following:

```
@login_required
def LogDisplay(request):

    print(request.user.id)
```

However, when I go to the url associated with this method, I get an integer as an output on my console.

How can I make it so that my first method has access to the current user as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

in views.py:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

get(self, request, format=None):
    ...
```

Comment: I get a "You do not have permission to perform this action." in my API response

Comment: That is because your user is not authenticated. REST Framework has different ways to handle authentication. Refer to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) to find which is more suitable for you.